# motion blue and black image on built in server - saved images are ok

Tags: colors, video, camera, motion

I'm experimenting motion on my desktop,

My webcam: Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270

Output Images and video are ok but the image on built in server aren't. They are like blue and black - almost monochromatic but sometimes it get gray also.

I've tried open with vlc and it's ok - I think it's related with the video compression before transmit it to the server.

```
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion 4.0.1 Started
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to syslog
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (NTC)
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ENC] ffmpeg_init: ffmpeg libavcodec version 56.60.100 libavformat version 56.40.101
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] main: Motion running in setup mode.
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] main: Camera 0 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] main: Camera 0 is device: /dev/video0 input -1
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] main: Stream port 8081
    [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] main: Waiting for threads to finish, pid: 2787
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_init: Camera 0 started: motion detection Enabled
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] vid_v4lx_start: Using videodevice /dev/video0 and input -1
    [0:web_control] [NTC] [STR] http_bindsock: listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080
    [0:web_control] [NTC] [STR] httpd_run: Started motion-httpd server on port 8080 (auth Disabled)
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_get_capability:
    ------------------------
    cap.driver: "uvcvideo"
    cap.card: "UVC Camera (046d:0825)"
    cap.bus_info: "usb-0000:00:12.2-1"
    cap.capabilities=0x84200001
    ------------------------
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_get_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_get_capability: - STREAMING
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_select_input: name = "Camera 1", type 0x00000002, status 00000000
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_select_input: - CAMERA
    [1:ml1] [WRN] [VID] v4l2_select_input: Device doesn't support VIDIOC_G_STD
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_set_pix_format: Config palette index 17 (YU12) doesn't work.
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_set_pix_format: Supported palettes:
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_set_pix_format: (0) YUYV (YUYV 4:2:2)
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_set_pix_format: 0 - YUYV 4:2:2 (compressed : 0) (0x56595559)
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_set_pix_format: (1) MJPG (Motion-JPEG)
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_set_pix_format: 1 - Motion-JPEG (compressed : 1) (0x47504a4d)
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_set_pix_format Selected palette YUYV
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_do_set_pix_format: Testing palette YUYV (320x240)
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_do_set_pix_format: Using palette YUYV (320x240) bytesperlines 640 sizeimage 153600 colorspace 00000008
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980900, "Brightness", range 0,255
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls:         "Brightness", default 128, current 128
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980901, "Contrast", range 0,255
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls:         "Contrast", default 32, current 32
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980902, "Saturation", range 0,255
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls:         "Saturation", default 32, current 32
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980918, "Power Line Frequency", range 0,2
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls:         "Power Line Frequency", default 2, current 2
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980913, "Gain", range 0,255
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_scan_controls:         "Gain", default 64, current 192
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] vid_v4lx_start: Using V4L2
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [STR] http_bindsock: listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8081
    [1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_init: Started motion-stream server on port 8081 (auth Disabled)
```

[image: Strange imagem from built in motion server]

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=72515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running 'motion -s' was the cause of the trouble.
'motion start' made it work.